# for loop to check on cell.textlabel or cell.tag

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, cell

can anyone please help me with how to access a specific cell with its tag or text label, i have a table view with a list of buttons above, those buttons filed with the thumbnail of the cell when ever the cell was clicked then also the background of the cell goes red.

when i click on the cell once again - when its red - the background goes white - default - also the thumbnail removed from the button above.

also when i click on the button the photo in it should disappear as well as the background of the cell itself, it should go white. and thats what i couldnt do .. can anyone help me with that, how to access the the cell to change its background when the cell.tag or cell. texlabel.text is given.

thanx in advance

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("intrest") as UITableViewCell
    cell.tag = indexPath.row + 1
    cell.textLabel?.text = InterstArr[indexPath.row]
    var img = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 3, width: 40 , height: 40))
    img.image = UIImage(named:"\(InterstArr[indexPath.row]).png")


    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    cell.indentationLevel = 1
    cell.indentationWidth = 45
    cell.addSubview(img)
    return cell
}
```

I did it with the help of @natuslaedo ... i just stored the value of the index path when i clicked on the row .. then in my if statements to check on the 5 buttons above and deselect them, i took the indexpath stored and accessed the cell to change its color ... i initialise the index paths variables like this `var firstIP:NSIndexPath!`

Comment: i'm not sure to understand, are the buttons inside your cells??

Comment: no .. they are above the uitableview @Saliom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, add the following line to your **didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** function:

```
yourTableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
```

And target selector for your button is like as follows:

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    // Code to remove photo from your button
    // ......

    // To remove background effect of cell
    let indexPaths:Array<NSIndexPath> = yourTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as Array<NSIndexPath>
    // If you have implemented your own class which inherits from UITableViewCell, use its name while type casting and explicit typing
    for indexPath in indexPaths {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = yourTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
        // REMOVE BACKGROUND EFFECT HERE (using cell)
    }
}
```

Comment: it says downcasting from uitableviewcell ?  to uitableviewcell only unwarps optionals

Comment: That means you have not used UITableViewCell objects as table view cells. Just use the name of the class you have used. I mean, let cell:MyTableViewCellClass = yourTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexpath) as MyTableViewCellClass

Comment: i am sorry .. but what do u mean by MyTableViewCellClass ?? my table is in a normal uiviewcontroller  .. i posted the cellForRowAtIndexPath so u can help me more .. thanx

Comment: Usually developers create their own table view cell classes which inherit from UITableViewCell. If you did not, you may use the updated answer. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: it works fine .. thanx .. but only for the first button clicked .. i can chose up to 5 cells and then 5 buttons appeared above ... how can i make it for all buttons ? i have 5 diffrent 5 if statement to check which button is clicked and putting that code in each one of them didnt work out

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to match on tag or text content, everything should be based on row or index path so that it correlates back to your data model.

Consider creating a custom class for your button data storage so you have an array with one entry per button and the class holds the index path of the associated cell, the image, etc. Then, when a button is clicked it's easy to update your main data model and the cell (if it's visible).

Comment: there will be more than one selected cell at a time .. it can be up to 5 cells selected .. discarding the tag and the text, how to reach that specific cell with its indexPath out side the overrided functions

Comment: That's fine, so you have 5 buttons and 5 items in your array. You just need to match the button to the array index (which could be done using tag)

Comment: exactly .. i just wanna know how to reach that specific cell via its tag or text label .. i have them stored already .. but i dont know to code that line of code to search among cells till matched

Comment: You can't search among cells, since the only cells that exist are the ones displayed plus one or two.  UITableView doesn't create and maintain all the cells; only those it needs to display what's on the screen.  It then, as you scroll, will reuse cells that disappear for the new cells that are coming into view.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `indexPath` of cell in click event this way,

```
func buttonClick(sender:UIButton)
{
    let position: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(position)
    {
        println(indexPath.row)
        println(indexPath.section)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to match buttons in a cell with your data model is to store the indexPath of the cell with the cell.  When the button is tapped, your target method which is a method on the cell, will get called and you can use the indexPath and pass it up to your data model using a delegate call.

I'd give you more details but I am not sure if that is what you are asking.